# Durable leak-proof connections / couplings for corrugated drainage pipes

Tags: pipe, drainage

PVC pipes can be joined using couplers and glue to form a durable water tight connection. I have not had any such luck with corrugated pipes - and have had to deal with the consequences of leaking pipes pieced together by landscaping contractors.

[image]

The latest I have heard is that they are coupled by rotating the second section into the first. That is just not at all reassuring since that approach has failed repeatedly. I'm not comfortable with purely "mechanical" solutions : but cement/glue does not seem to be a thing for corrugated pipe?  What are the options here?

**Update**  I am dealing with a number of pipes like this *already buried* and/or *already leading down off the property*.  I can not readily just change to another method of drainage. It is a matter of getting the best result with exactly this type of corrugated pipe. For future I will take these difficulties into account *when I actually have the chance to be in control of the decision* .

Comment: True - i'll update the photo

Comment: Rotating one inside the other only works if the corrugation is like a thread. For the pipe you show thr ridges are parallel which won’t act like a thread.

Comment: i've used shoe goo to join similar piping. coat the inside "female", twist the male after inserting. worked for draining a pool with a siphon. – dandavis 22 mins ago

Comment: @dandavis  I have not been able to get an insert to work even after cutting a section with a box knife. It is difficult to constrict and hurts my wrists even to get a couple of sections.  It looks like i'll need a real coupler - which I've also tried without success so far.

Comment: you might try heating up the female half with a torch or hot air gun. While hot, you can stick two boards in the end and spread them apart to (slightly) stretch the pipe and make it easier for the snake to swallow its tail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After multiple trial and errors the following did result in a water-tight seal:

- place rubber-tape / water *proof* tape inside a coupler on the downward end
- place rubber-tape / water *proof* tape around the entire outside of the  coupler
- layers of gorilla tape or similar high strength water-resistant tape on top of and around the rubber/waterproof tape

In addition ensure the proper leveling of the pipes. I had to do some more digging to correct a section of pipe that had a positive slope.

Answer (score 3):

Corrugated drain pipes don't do waterproof joins, or particularly secure ones. You're supposed to bury it and then the dirt holds everything in place, and keeps most of the water inside

So they're are no good if there is any head of pressure that comes above the surface of the ground.  because you'll get an undesired water feature (like a pond or a fountain) at the join.

If you need to handle water under slight pressure you'll need to use a different type of pipe, eg: PVC.

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question with detail that these are pre-exsiting pipes and I am not in a position to change these out unless getting a backhoe to dig them  out.

Comment: either you have too much water going into the pipes or they are partially blocked.

Comment: Not either one.  I'm trying to provide tight join of sections of existing corrugated pipe. We had work done on foundation piers and they have been severed as part of that process. Just need to zip them back up well.  In other cases there is a steeply sloped section in which I added extension: need to make that tight as well.

Comment: Just push them back together then, and bury them.

Comment: critical not to have leaks - that won't fly . Wow this is hard to achieve

Comment: This type of pipe is for rain or ground water, why is it critical not to have that leak into the ground.

Comment: This is for a steep section that was being properly protected by the pipe before the breakages.

Comment: @WestCoastProjects; You can pack the couplings on both sides with an RTV silicone caulking and make sure it has "set-up" before using the pipe.

Comment: @d.george  I'll try that approach out on a test section

Answer (score 3):

If you are going to use drainage pipe that will buried more than 12" or have any weight on it, you should not use that corrugated piping. I used it for drainage in depths between 2 and 5 feet and it crushed reducing the flow rate. I had to replace it with sch35 drainage pipe.(It cost a lot more to do it right).

The pipe you show is used by many contractors and home owners for all the wrong reasons; it is cheap and light and can be handled by one person and NO, the joints will not be water tight.

My 2 cents.

Comment: This is helpful for those in the _planning_ stages.  I already have tens of meters of buried pipe so am looking for how to handle these in the current state.